# Where is a good place to find survey results?

Tags: dataset, survey

Sites like eMarketer offer general survey results about internet usage.

Who else has a big set of survey results, or regularly releases them?

- Preferably marketing research focused.

Thanks!

Comment: I think a general wiki for where to get data is great, with a section for survey data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best place to find survey data related to the social sciences is the ICPSR data clearinghouse: http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/access/index.jsp

Also, the 'survey' tag on Infochimps has many interesting and free data sets: http://infochimps.org/tags/survey

Comment: I'm not sure how many of these will have the scope of "marketing" research, but I would also suggest the OP check out ICPSR. It is also good to know the quality of the sampling and data record keeping, which I imagine could be haphazard if you get data from a proprietary, non-education related source.

Comment: To those recommending ICPSR data: Unfortunately, ICPSR data is mostly 'restricted' -- i.e., unless you're paying tuition at a 'member organization', you may well not find any data appropriate to your needs at all. To complicate matters further, the filtered search ICSPR provides only claims to let you filter out restricted data. In fact, it returns both restricted and unrestricted results. I.e., ICPSR is not about disseminating data; it's about locking it up.

Answer (score 2):

government websites usually .... I use the [RITA](http://www.rita.dot.gov/) a lot